# Is data access in a 16x16 array faster than a 256x256 array?

Tags: arrays

I was working upon something, and stumbled across this hurdle while programming.
Is data access in a 16x16 array faster than a 256x256 array? The only thing that created doubt in my mind is that modern day computers can access data randomly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

For why, see Ulrich Drepper's excellent paper, [*What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory*](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/cpumemory.pdf), which explains subjects such as CPU data caches and their impact on memory access time.